# Self-built Automator action does not work when used in Automator service or App

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods, automator, podio

I wrote a **Cocoa Automator** action that uses the Pod **PodioKit**. Everything works fine when used in an Automator workflow, the method `- (id)runWithInput:(id)input fromAction:(AMAction *)anAction error:(NSDictionary **)errorInfo` is called and all steps work.

The problem occurs when I try to build an **Automator service** or an **Automator app** using the same action. The method `- (id)runWithInput:(id)input fromAction:(AMAction *)anAction error:(NSDictionary **)errorInfo` is called, I can read the results from `NSLog()` calls. BUT all calls of PodioKit methods are completely ignored, just like they weren't there. Automator seems to jump over the calls :-/

Maybe someone ran into similar problems and found a checkbox, a build setting or anything like this to let Automator services take care about external APIs/Pods. Or maybe a good tipp/ question into the right direction...

Comment: Sebastian from Podio here. How are you including PodioKit in your project and how do you import it? Are you using CocoaPods? I am not too familiar with Automator development, but maybe some code snippets would help. Also, did you try debugging using breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I use CocoaPods and it works fine. Debugging is not trivial while building Automator actions, so I use a lot of `NSLog()` calls.

All `NSLogs()` work and give output to the console.app except the `NSLog()` inside the PodioKit calls both in error forks or success forks. The PodioKit calls are ignored completely...

Everything works as expected when building an ordinary Automator workflow using my Podio action. I don't think that the PodioKit is to blame, I think there is something special to think about when building an Automator action...

Comment: Yes it definitely sounds like its out of PodioKit's control. If you manage to find a solution, please share!